# Why Does The JVM Return This Integer?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, rounding

I have made quite a simple number rounding application, since I am quite a beginner, there may be some errors, some debugging to do and we could go on and on however that is not why I am here. Whenever I type in an integer that is larger than the capacity of the value "int", it either returns "-1" or an incredibly large small number (it's negative so further away from zero) such as "-572589576". I want to why and how the JVM returns this. The code for my program is listed below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberRounder {
private static Scanner userInput2;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("--- Number Rounder ---");

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The number you enter will round it to the nearest value.");
    System.out.print("Enter any decimal number: ");

    if (userInput.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("\nCalculating...");
        System.out.println("Number Rounding...");
        double chosenNumber = userInput.nextDouble();
        int roundedNumber = (int) Math.round(chosenNumber);
        if (roundedNumber == -1) {
            System.out.println("\nAn ERROR occured.");
            System.out.println("That number is too large for our servers. Sorry for the inconvenience.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println(chosenNumber + " has been rounded to " + roundedNumber);
    } else if (!(userInput.hasNextDouble())) {
        System.out.println("\nThat is an illegal response...");
        userInput2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nThe number you enter will round it to the nearest value.");
        System.out.print("Enter any decimal number between 1-10: ");
        double chosenNumber = userInput2.nextDouble();
        int roundedNumber = (int) Math.round(chosenNumber);
        System.out.println(chosenNumber + " has been rounded to " + roundedNumber);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Something wrong happened...");
    }
}
}
```

I have solved the problem of when it returns "-1" however I still don't know how to completely solve this problem. That is why I am here asking the question:
Why does the JVM return such as random number?

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever I type in an integer that is **larger than the capacity of the value "int"**

What did you expect to get from it? Exception?

it will not be there. Java just circle from MAX_VALUE to MIN_VALUE

Just try:

```
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
    System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

And look what it prints.

PS. that is about how number sign represented in actual binary format of int value.

Comment: the smallest value for the value type int is printed to the screen: -2147483648.

Comment: I still have one question remaining however. Why doesn't the JVM crash and terminate the program if I type in a value over the MAX_VALUE of Integer? Shouldn't it crash?

Comment: No. JVM does not crash. It is what it is and is there from the beginning of Java. You have to live with that :-)

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the feedback, I have applied all the changes and now my project (mini project) looks better than before. Thanks.

Comment: @VishS. 32-bit values with overflow are inherited from C. It has been this way for 40+ years.

Comment: @VishS. if you use `hasNextInt()` it would tell you the number is not a valid `int` value, and if you used `nextInt()` it would throw an exception. You would only write the code the way you have to avoid such an error.

Comment: Fun fact `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're forcing a `double` (64-bits) into an `int`, so the resulting value is truncated and you see these "random" (although they're not random) values. You should use a `long` to provide additional space for your numbers.

Comment: Yes they are not random

Comment: I will change the code so it can further provide additional space for the numbers. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @VishS. in that case you shouldn't be using `double` or `int` but `BigInteger` for arbitrarily large integers.